# Pass PHP variable to Javascript function whitin an AJAX request possible?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I try to pass a variable from Javascript (when choosing some option in a form) to a PHP file which calls a SQL query.

The SQL query (a string) should be handed over to a Javascript function and the function should be executed. Everything in one click. Is that somehow possible?

I tried that with a AJAX request but when I use this for my last step:

```
var javascriptstring;
      $.getJSON('getstring.php', function(data) {
        javascriptstring = data.value;
        });
```

> I get the exception: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

And it prints out "undefined"

.HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
     function showString(time) {
  if (time=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getstring.php?q="+time,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

      var javascriptstring;
      $.getJSON('getstring.php', function(data) {
        javascriptstring = data.value;
        });
        document.write(javascriptstring);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
    <select name="somestring" onchange="showString(this.value)">
    <option value="">No string selected</option>
    <option value="1">String 1</option>
    </select>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>String will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=Twitter user=postgres password=****");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . pg_errormessage($con));
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM tswholeworld WHERE createdat > (NOW() - INTERVAL '".$q."hour');";
$result = pg_query($con,$sql);

    $string = "";
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $lat = $row['latitude'];
    $lon = $row['longitude'];
    $string .= "new google.maps.LatLng({$lat}, {$lon}), ";
}
echo '{"value": "'.$string.'"}';
pg_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this much amount of AJAX should suffice. Actually `document.write` replaces the whole DOM with the current. I have removed that and modified your function. Also I have removed the native Ajax code since you already have jQuery so no point in adding that big code. This small function will get the JSON data and print the value that the server is sending

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function showString(time) {
    if (time=="") {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
    } 
    $.getJSON('getstring.php?q='+time, function(data) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = data.value;
    });
}
</script>
```

Edit: Please close the external script tags

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  //your script
</script>
```

Comment: ok that looks nice but somehow it still doesn't work. I guess it's because my PHP doesn't get its variable anymore through: xmlhttp.open("GET","getstring.php?q="+time,true); anymore?

Comment: I can see your jquery script not closed. `<script src=jquery></script><script> your script </script>`

Comment: @Andrej You were doing the same thing with Native Ajax then you are doing the thing again with jQuery Ajax. So if you have access to Jquery why not use only jquery so I have removed the native ajax code

Comment: yes but the code of my PHP needs the GET thing. ($q = intval($_GET['q']);). How do i rewrite that than?

Comment: already passing `$.getJSON('getstring.php?q='+time` see the q variable this should be available in php

Comment: thanks for your help i could solve some part of my problem but now the Google API function which i originally wanted to hand over this PHP variable throws an exception but i will make a new question for it because it's somehow a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close script tag

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>// close include external javascript tag
```

Then you call your function inside script tag

```
<script>
function showString(time) {

-----Your code----

</script>
```

Comment: it is closed just scroll down the code a little bit

Comment: You can include external javascript as `<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>` close with `</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Keep the Javascript function definition in `head` or before the `select` tag. like below -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type='text/javascript'>
       function showString(time) {
         if (time=="") {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
         return;
       } 
       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
       }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","getstring.php?q="+time,true);
       xmlhttp.send();

       var javascriptstring;
       $.getJSON('getstring.php', function(data) {
        javascriptstring = data.value;
        });
       document.write(javascriptstring);

     }

     </script>

   </head>
   <body>
     <form>
       <select name="somestring" onchange="showString(this.value)">
         <option value="">No string selected</option>
         <option value="1">String 1</option>
       </select>
     </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: ok thank you, changed that but the idea of my code still doesn't work